# jQuery: Extract value from an element and insert it into a field on a repeatable list form field

Tags: jquery

I have a form and in the form I have a repeatable list. I can't have other fields than a text input in that repeatable list. Therefore, in order to allow users to submit images, I keep the file upload input separated from the repeatable list field as shown below.

[image: My form]

I was wondering whether I can use jQuery to get the names of the files in the file upload field and insert them into the repeatable list field in its' respective columns.

Looking at the markup the form produces, I feel that it's possible only that my jQuery knowledge doesn't allow me to think of a solution.

Here's the markup that makes up the repeatable list

```
<div class="ginput_container ginput_container_list ginput_list">
    <table class="gfield_list gfield_list_container">
        <colgroup>
            <col id="gfield_list_2_col_1" class="gfield_list_col_odd">
                <col id="gfield_list_2_col_2" class="gfield_list_col_even">
                    <col id="gfield_list_2_col_3" class="gfield_list_col_odd">
                        <col id="gfield_list_2_col_4" class="gfield_list_col_even">
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Side</th>
                <th scope="col">Reference</th>
                <th scope="col">Notes</th>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="gfield_list_group gfield_list_row_odd">
                <td class="gfield_list_cell gfield_list_2_cell1" data-label="Side">
                    <input aria-label="Side" type="text" name="input_2[]" value="">
                </td>
                <td class="gfield_list_cell gfield_list_2_cell2" data-label="Reference">
                    <input aria-label="Reference" type="text" name="input_2[]" value="">
                </td>
                <td class="gfield_list_cell gfield_list_2_cell3" data-label="Notes">
                    <input aria-label="Notes" type="text" name="input_2[]" value="">
                </td>
                <td class="gfield_list_icons">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_list_item " aria-label="Add another row" onclick="gformAddListItem(this, 0)" onkeypress="gformAddListItem(this, 0)"><img src="localhost/images/list-add.svg" alt="" title="Add a new row"></a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="delete_list_item" aria-label="Remove this row" onclick="gformDeleteListItem(this, 0)" onkeypress="gformDeleteListItem(this, 0)" style="visibility: visible;"><img src="localhost/images/list-remove.svg" alt="" title="Remove this row"></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="gfield_list_group gfield_list_row_even">
                <td class="gfield_list_cell gfield_list_2_cell1" data-label="Side">
                    <input aria-label="Side" type="text" name="input_2[]" value="">
                </td>
                <td class="gfield_list_cell gfield_list_2_cell2" data-label="Reference">
                    <input aria-label="Reference" type="text" name="input_2[]" value="">
                </td>
                <td class="gfield_list_cell gfield_list_2_cell3" data-label="Notes">
                    <input aria-label="Notes" type="text" name="input_2[]" value="">
                </td>
                <td class="gfield_list_icons">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_list_item " aria-label="Add another row" onclick="gformAddListItem(this, 0)" onkeypress="gformAddListItem(this, 0)"><img src="localhost/images/list-add.svg" alt="" title="Add a new row"></a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="delete_list_item" aria-label="Remove this row" onclick="gformDeleteListItem(this, 0)" onkeypress="gformDeleteListItem(this, 0)" style="visibility: visible;"><img src="localhost/images/list-remove.svg" alt="" title="Remove this row"></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And here's the markup that produces the file upload filenames preview

```
<div id="gform_preview_5_3">
    <div id="o_1dn37jigsu7cu20drk138i17k0f" class="ginput_preview"><img class="gform_delete" src="localhost/images/delete.png" onclick="gformDeleteUploadedFile(5,3, this);" onkeypress="gformDeleteUploadedFile(5,3, this);" alt="Delete this file" title="Delete this file"> <strong>Doa Ditimpa Musibah.jpg</strong></div>
    <div id="o_1dn37jd93vp41aic1030166912o8a" class="ginput_preview"><img class="gform_delete" src="localhost/images/delete.png" onclick="gformDeleteUploadedFile(5,3, this);" onkeypress="gformDeleteUploadedFile(5,3, this);" alt="Delete this file" title="Delete this file"> <strong>surah-al-layl.jpg</strong></div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for the help! In the meantime, I will continue to try something out!

Comment: Here's what I came up with so far on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pmu1n3a6/1/) - if I can figure out how to dynamically get the nth-child, and make the variables multiply dynamically according to the rows, it would be awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am closing this question and below is my solution for this task. It is not dynamic and automated but it will do. I will make 10 variables and 10 conditions hoping users don't upload more than 10 files. If anyone can show me how to write a dynamic, automated jQuery script, it will be awesome!

```
var str = $( "#gform_preview_5_3 div:nth-child(1) strong" ).text();
var str2 = $( "#gform_preview_5_3 div:nth-child(2) strong" ).text();

$( ".gfield_list_group:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2) input " ).val( str );
$( ".gfield_list_group:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2) input " ).val( str2 );
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pmu1n3a6/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you may now include your file upload in the repeatable list by using this

```
<input aria-label="Reference" type="file" id="file_upload" name="input_2[]" value="">

$('#file_upload').change(function(){

  var img_file = $('#file_upload').prop('files')[0];
  console.log(img_file);//this will show all properties of the uploaded file

  //you can get the file name through 
  var file_name = img_file.name;

});
```

Comment: Thanks @YXN for your answer. Unfortunately the form comes from a WordPress plugin and it doesn’t support using File Upload field in the Repeatable List field.

Comment: what wordpress plugin is that?

Comment: It’s called Gravity Form. Previously, I attempted to change the textfield in the repeatable list to file upload and succeeded. However it doesn’t store any value for form processing and submission. I posted the issue on StackOverflow, asked the plugin developer and also a programmer friend - and couldn’t find a solution. Hence I came up with this idea above to separate the file upload field but to reference it to the repeatable list.

Comment: have you checked the docs here? https://docs.gravityforms.com/file-upload-field/#container or maybe we have not checked on $_FILE as like $_POST?

Comment: Yes I believe some major programming needs to be done in order to get the file upload field fully working in a repeatable list. I am not a programmer unfortunately. I posted on SO and didn’t get an answer as well

Comment: ok I understand, if whoever may get to fix it, please let them check the docs on how to construct the html for gravity form dependencies and it will be working.

Comment: unfortunately I can't because I am under company policies